# How to extract a new type alias from an object's value

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion

How to extract a new type alias from an object's value

```
const test = {
'a': ['music','bbq','shopping'],
'b': ['move','work']
};
```

How to get it from a test object

```
type Types = 'music' | 'bbq' | 'shopping' | 'move' | 'work'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using `as const`:

```
const test = {
'a': ['music','bbq','shopping'],
'b': ['move','work']
} as const;

type Elements = typeof test[keyof typeof test][number];
```

The only solution I can think of that is not using `as const` is defining an interface with the exact elements of the arrays:

```
interface Foo {
    a: ['music', 'bbq', 'shopping'],
    b: ['move', 'work']
};

type Elements2 = Foo[keyof Foo][number];
```

Comment: That's the desired effect, but I have a question, what exactly does as const do

Comment: @laterday It simply makes sure that you can't later modify the object, which would also invalidate the typing. Without it, typescript will not be able to infer the exact values and `Elements2` would simply just be `string`.

Comment: Is it understandable that if it is not as const, Elements2 will be inferred as string instead of the exact value

Comment: @laterday exactly, sorry if my wording has gotten you confused ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
const test = {
  'a': ['music','bbq','shopping'] as const,
  'b': ['move','work'] as const
};

type Types = test.a[number] | test.b[number]
```

Comment: This is wrong, you can't find the namespace "test", and test probably has a lot of keys like a and B. Is there a way to loop through instead of typing a and b manually